# How to use <div> tag to show and hide list of elements on jsp page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Somelablename: abc,123
                   asdf,234
                   pmjklj,2345        showmorelink

(onclick of the showmorelink remaining list should be visible, like:-)

```
Somelablename: abc,123
               asdf,234
               pmjklj,2345      showlesslink
               gggg,4444
               hhhhh,55555
```

(onclick of showlesslink the output should be as in the beginning)

Now I'm using a new row to display more elements but I need to know how to display the more elements in the same row .

```
<tr id="show">
       <td><strong><h:outputText value="#{msg['label.lablename']}" /> </strong></td>
    <td >
          <c:forEach items="${ManagedBean.Map1 }" var="list">
       <a href="#" onclick="Display1('${list.key}');"> ${list.value}</a>
        </br>
      </c:forEach>                                          
    </td>   


  <td>
   <span id='ShowMore'>                                         
    <a href="#" onClick="showDetails('Details','ShowMore','more');return false"                                         
     <h:outputText value="#{msg['showmorelink']}" />                                            
      </a> </span>
  </td>                                             
</tr>



<tr id="Details">                                                       
<td>
 <c:forEach items="${ManagedBean.Map2 }" var="list">                                        
  <a href="#" onclick="Display1('${list.key}');">${list.value}</a></br></c:forEach>                                                                                     
</td>                                       
<td >                               
 <a href="#" onClick="showDetails('ShowMore','Details','less');return false;"
<h:outputText value="#{msg['showlesslink']}" />                             
</a>                                
</td>                               
</tr>
```

Comment: where the elements that you want to display are stored in the bean or just few elements you want to add ?

Comment: At the first I'm supposed to display only 3 elements(dispalyed as link) and a showmore link beside it. onclick of this showmore link next set or elements should be displayed along with the first set, and this time showless link will be displayed and showmore link should be hidden. So for this reason, in the managed bean I'm using two maps, one to store first 3 elements only. second one to store remaining elements.

Comment: did you try the js code in my answer it's easier

Answer (score 0):

try this code it may help you :

exp of links :

```
<div id="myList">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
   <a href="#">8</a>


</div>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

JS code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList a").size();

    x=5;

    if (x==5) {
    $("#showLess").hide();
            }


    $('#myList a:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+3 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;

  if (x>5) {
    $("#showLess").show();
            }

        if (x==size_li) {
    $("#loadMore").hide();
            } 
        $('#myList a:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-3<5) ? 5 : x-3;

        if (x<size_li) {
    $("#showLess").hide();    
    $("#loadMore").show();
            }

        $('#myList a').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

css :

```
#myList a{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Result :

http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/3278/